# Given a pdf $f_{Y}(y)$ and $n$ random observations. Find probability that last observation will be the smallest number in all the sample?

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose that n observations are chosen at random from a continuous pdf fY(y). What is the probability that the last observation recorded will be the smallest number in the entire sample?

**attempt**: Suppose that $n$ observations are chosen at random from a continous pdf $f_{Y}(y)$.
THen the cdf is defined as $F_{Y}(y) = P(Y \leq y)$.

Then the probability that the last observation recorded will be the smallest number n the entire sample is

$P(y_{n} = y_{1}) = P[(y_{1} \leq y_{n}) \cap (y_{2} \leq y_{n}) \cap ....(y_{n-1} \leq y_{n})]$ =  $P[(y_{1} \leq y_{n})]P[(y_{2} \leq y_{n})]P[(y_{n-1} \leq y_{n})]$ = $[F_{Y}(y)]^{n-1}$

This problem is from the section ordered statistics.

Is this a correct way? Please any feedback would be really appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Also, see answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4262252/five-observations-have-been-drawn-independently-and-at-random-from-a-continuous/4262289#4262289).

Comment: Note missing assumptions about IID sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $n$ iid random variables, $\{Y_1, \ldots, Y_n\}$, and wish to know the probability that the $Y_n$ is less than all of the others.  You know the probability density function $f_Y$ and have found the cumulative distribution function $F_Y$.

You have *almost* got it.  What you have is the probability that a *specific value* of $Y_n$ is the greatest of the array.

What you need is to find the *expectation* of the probability that $Y_n$ has the *least value* of the array.

$$\mathsf P\left[\bigcap_{k=1}^{n-1}(Y_k > Y_n)\right] = \int_{\mathbb Y_n} \biggl(1-F_Y(y_n)\biggr)^{n-1} f_Y(y_n)\operatorname d y_n $$

---

Of course, there is a **much** more elegant solution.   If all variables are independently and identically distributed, then is there not an *equal* probability that any one of them will be the least ordered statistic?

$$\mathsf P\left[\bigcap_{k=1}^{n-1}(Y_k > Y_n)\right] = \frac 1 n$$

Comment: Do we have to multiply by n? So $f_{min}(y) = n(1-f_{Y}(y))^{(n-1)}f_Y(y)$. This could be the answer?

Comment: No, there is only one arrangement of the favoured space.  We're not looking for the probability that a value is the least order statistic, we're looking for the probability that the last sampled variable is the least.

Answer (score 0):

Continuous does not imply uniform. There's no reason to believe that each outcome is equally likely.

The problem does not state i.i.d. This is an assumption of one of the problem solvers and not the problem itself.

Comment: Right, but @GrahamPeck's answer does not assume uniform distribution.

Comment: It’s been almost 6 years since I provided this answer, but perhaps there was another answer that was deleted? EDIT: In fact, I’m pretty confident there was. The wording of my answer connects the i.i.d. idea as belonging to a different person than the person to whom this addresses.